# ADF autoSuggestBehavior how to get select event?

Tags: jsf, listener, autosuggest, oracle-adf

I have an inputText with autoSuggestionBehavior on it. 
As I saw in the *autoSuggestionBehavior*'s tag documentation, there's no way to get noticed that you picked something from the list. The only way you can do that is with a valueChangeListener on the inputText.
My HUGE problem is that the listener is called twice if I type only a fraction of the whole word I'm selecting.
Example:
I type: *Buc* and then click on *Bucharest* from the suggested list, my Listener is called first for *Buc* and then again for *Bucharest*. 
How can I know that after the first call with *Buc* I will have another call with *Bucharest* ?
I need this !!! With richfaces or icefaces things were normal, where did ADF got from the *awsome* idea to implement it like this ?

Comment: is your inputText autosubmitting?

Comment: yeah, otherwise the ValueChangeListener doesn't get fired.

Comment: I don't see a way out of this one. Selecting from the autoSuggest results will result in the inputText losing focus and auto submitting.

Comment: yeah. maybe with some complicated javascript which doesn't worth bothering. why did oracle implemented like this ?

Comment: I believe this is fixed in the new release!